# BigQuery Create a table from Query Results

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery

New to the Big Query API.  Trying to just do a basic query and have it save to a table.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the below.(I have read the similar questions posted about this topic)  I don't get an error but it also doesn't save the results in a table like I want.

Any thoughts/advice?

```
import argparse
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials




credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

query_request = bigquery_service.jobs()
query_data = {
    'query': (
        'SELECT * '
        'FROM [analytics.ddewber_acq_same_day] limit 5;'),
    'destinationTable':{
        "projectId": 'XXX-XXX-XXX',
        "datasetId": 'analytics',
        "tableId": "ddewber_test12"
        },
        "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
}

query_response = query_request.query(
    projectId='XXX-XXX-XXX',
    body=query_data).execute()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the difference between [Jobs: query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query) (that you use in your example) and [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) (that you should use) APIs
Hope this gives you direction to fix your code

Comment: It did not give me direction it took me to where I came from.  What is the python API call to do this?